# Counting words in python

Tags: python, list, logging, dictionary, system

Can anyone tell me how to count the number of times a word appears in a dictionary.  Iv already read a file into the terminal into a list.  would I need to put the list into a dictionary or start put reading the file into the terminal into a dictionary and not a list? the file is a log file if that matters...

Comment: Please be more precise. Can you give an example, how your list looks like in principal?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into `collections.Counter`. Your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

short example:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'red blue red green blue blue'

Counter(s.split())
> Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})

Counter(s.split()).most_common(2)
> [('blue', 3), ('red', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.Counter has it.

The example given there meets your requirement i suppose

```
from collections import Counter
import re
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open('log file here.txt').read().lower())
cont = Counter(words)
#to get the count of required_word
print cont['required_word']
```